# Assertion in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using Assertion in my test case to check whether the element contains the current time and also a string field along with it.

For example, if my current time is 1:00 pm, then code should check whether the element contains "1:0) PM to Clock-out"

Currently I have written the code to check the current time is there in the element, but I need to concatenate the word "to Clock-out" along with it.

Below is the code which checks for current time:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
        .xpath("//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-summary-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ion-card/ion-row[1]/ion-col/ion-row[2]/div[1]")));
String element = driver
        .findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-summary-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ion-card/ion-row[1]/ion-col/ion-row[2]/div[1]"))
        .getText();
Assert.assertTrue(element.contains(new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm").format(new java.util.Date())));
```

Can anyone please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append the string with the date you got from java.

Below is the code for it:

```
Assert.assertTrue(element.contains((new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(new java.util.Date()).toString()+" to Clock-out"))));
```